# Sort Order Rows/Cols and the Entries of an Adjacency Matrix

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I've worked the following code to produce the correct adjacency matrix. However, I would like the rows and columns to align to an alpha or numerical sort of the vertices. For instance, this code produces the TableHeadings A D B C across the top row and down the left-most column. Instead, I would like the TableHeadings to be A B C D across the top row and down the left-most column. The entries need to following that ordering as well. Any advice is most appreciated!!!! Also, can this be done for vertices with numerical names and not letter names?

```
Clear[edges]
edges = {A <-> D, A <-> B, B <-> D, C <-> C, D <-> A};
g = LayeredGraphPlot[edges, Left, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> ({Lighter[LightYellow], 
      EdgeForm[Lighter[Blue]], Disk[#, .15], Black, 
      Text[Style[#2, 9.5, Black], #1]} &)]
EdgeList[edges] // TableForm
v = VertexList[Graph[edges]];
am = AdjacencyMatrix[Graph[edges]];
TableForm[am, TableHeadings -> {v, v}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
order = Ordering[v]

(* {1, 3, 4, 2} *)

TableForm[am2 = (#[[order]] & /@ am)[[order]], 
 TableHeadings -> (Sort /@ {v, v})]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just construct your graph with the desired vertex ordering in the first place?

```
edges = {"A" <-> "D", "A" <-> "B", "B" <-> "D", "C" <-> "C", "D" <-> "A"};
```

Provide the explicit vertex list like so:

```
Graph[{"A", "B", "C", "D"}, edges]
```

Or like this:

```
Graph[Sort@VertexList[edges], edges]
```

Comment: Hi Szabolcs: This works very nicely too! If I have a directed set of edges then I will need to takes directedness into account ...

Comment: edges = {TX -> R1, R1 -> R3, R5 -> RX, TX -> R2, R2 -> R4, R4 -> R6, 
  R6 -> RX, R1 -> R2, R2 -> R3, R4 -> R5, R5 -> R6, TX -> R7, 
  TX -> R8, R7 -> R9, R9 -> R6, R9 -> RX, R8 -> R6}